# How do I re-enable the backlight?

Tags: 11.10, hp, backlight

Since Oneiric, if I leave my machine (HP Mini 110 netbook) unattended and it goes into power-save mode, the backlight gets disabled. How can I turn it back on? Note that the keyboard backlight controls (<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>) don't have any effect in this situation.

I've already [filed a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/881166), but filing a bug doesn't fix my problem. I tried this workaround [posted in this bug report dealing with Acer laptops](https://bugs.launchpad.net/linux/+bug/779166/comments/49):

```
sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=0
```

However, if anything, that command makes things worse. In the general case, I can see a little bit if I'm in a dark room with a flashlight aimed just so. But after running `setpci` I can't see anything. And I find the `setpci` documentation to be utterly incomprehensible, so I don't know whether I need to tweak my command somehow or whether I'm completely barking up the wrong tree.

**Update:**
I've found a workaround: I'm now booting with the kernel parameter `acpi=off`. This disables power management, which prevents the machine from going into power saving mode and thus failing to come back up correctly. Of course, not having power management means that I can't use suspend or do anything to manage power other than powering it off (even then, I have to manually use the power switch). Also, it prevents me from using Unity 3D or Gnome Shell, forcing me into Unity 2C or Gnome Classic. So, I'd really like to be able to stop using this hack.

**Update 2:**
Midway through Oneiric's run, a kernel update fixed this issue. But this question is still relevant as a general procedure for working around showstopper kernel regressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a kernel bug. There are two workarounds. The first is to boot with `acpi=off` as described in the question. The second is to boot with a Natty kernel. This is much better, though it seems to make LibreOffice a bit crashy.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try hitting <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>? This usually triggers the backlight to turn on

Comment: Good suggestion. Unfortunately, it didn't work for me.

Comment: Can you tell us what your F4 key is when you use the Fn key?  It differs between mfr and models.

Comment: @lqlarry: Fn+F4 should increase the brightness on this machine, and Fn+F3 should decrease the brightness. Neither key has any effect.